# React Native Image component with "{width: 100%, height: auto}" gets dislocated when using margin

Tags: react-native, responsiveness

I have an Image component that has width from `Dimensions.get('window').width`,
and height that is calculated using this formula:

```
{ //not the real code, but it works exactly like this.
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  height: actualImageHeight*(Dimensions.get('window').width/actualImageWidth)
}
```

It basically closely emulates how `width: 100%, height: auto` works in css.

and it works well until i added margins to it, which causes the image to get dislocated
like this:
[Dislocated Bear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVaAV.jpg)

I have also tried to use `PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(margin*2)` to try taking account the margin, which makes the new formula look like this:

```
{ //not the real code, but it works exactly like this.
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width-PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(margin*2),
  height: actualImageHeight*((Dimensions.get('window').width-PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(margin*2))/actualImageWidth)
}
```

and the result is almost, there, but still slightly dislocated: [Slightly Dislocated Bear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpmI5.png)

Which makes me think that Dimensions isn't a good reference for width.

So how do I emulate `width: 100%, height: auto` that doesn't use Dimensions?

Is it possible to use `width: 100%` as a reference to use in the formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView,View,Dimensions,Image,} from 'react-native';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
const actualImageHeight = 200;
const actualImageWidth = 300;

const Test = props => {
return (
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View
    style={{
      width: width,
      height: actualImageHeight * (width / actualImageWidth),
      borderRadius: 6,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#f1f1f1',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      padding: 12,
    }}>
    <Image
      style={{flex: 1, width: null, height: null}}
      source={{uri: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'}}
    />
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
 );
};
```

when you place calculated width and height to any view if you place margin in styles it will dislocated the view because while rendering the view margin also considered. Better to wrap image with view.

Comment: omg, sometimes the best solution is the simple one, and wrapping it around a view and using padding instead of margin solved the problem! I even used onLayout image prop just to get the width, but needs to be rerendered to work. btw i also managed to make this work on lists with 2 or more columns simply by dividing the width by the column count. anyways thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I still continued the idea of subtracting the width with the margins, and I managed to make it work. Simply by doing `Dimensions.get('window').width-(margin*2)` will make it work. So final code is:

```
{
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width-(margin*2),
  height: actualImageHeight*(Dimensions.get('window').width-(margin*2)/actualImageWidth)
}
```

The result: [Bears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtyu2.png)

Full code of the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";

interface AnotherCardProps {
  thumbnail: string;
  margin?: number;
  column?: number;
  maxHeight?: number;
  minHeight?: number;
}

const AnotherCard: React.FC<AnotherCardProps> = (props) => {
  const [imageSize, setImageSize] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0, ratio: 0 });
  const margin = props.margin || 0;
  const column = props.column || 1;
  const newWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width / column - margin * 2;
  const maxHeight = props.maxHeight || newWidth * 1.5;
  const minHeight = props.minHeight || newWidth;

  useEffect(() => {
    Image.getSize(props.thumbnail, (w, h) =>
      setImageSize({
        width: w,
        height: h,
        ratio: newWidth / w,
      })
    );
  });

  return (
    <Image
      style={{
        borderRadius: 20,
        margin: margin,
        flex: 1,
        width: newWidth,
        height:
          imageSize.height * imageSize.ratio < minHeight
            ? minHeight
            : imageSize.height * imageSize.ratio > maxHeight
            ? maxHeight
            : imageSize.height * imageSize.ratio,
        resizeMode: "cover",
      }}
      source={{
        uri: props.thumbnail,
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default AnotherCard;
```